# concatenating a string with elements of list returns only the last element

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeutifulSoup to extract certain data from an html file and when I applied the following code to get as a final result, that is the concatenation of all the elements of a tag's children list, I only got the final element in the lyrics variable.

```
        lyrics = ""
        for content in songResult.children:
            if "br" in str(content):
                continue                  
            lyrics += str(content)
        print(lyrics)
```

the children are either br tags or text inside the songResult tag. I ignored the br tags and tried using `print(content)` instead of `lyrics += str(content)` then the printing went perfect. I can't seem to find out the origin of the problem. any suggestions, please?

Comment: Did you step through the code line-by-line in a debugger and observe what value `content` and `lyrics` had at each point? Did you check if the `continue` statement was being hit more often than you expected?

Comment: Is there a way you can supply the html file?

Comment: I guess I'm also confused as to what you're looking for as the output. If the only thing under the songResult tag is the br tag and the text, then getting that entire text wouldn't require to loop through the tags, since the lyrics are all under songResult (and no other tags except the <br>). then simply pulling the text under the songResult tag should get you the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me.  I did:

```
lyrics = ""

children = ['testbr', 'test', 'testbr2', 'test', 'testbr3']

for content in children:
    if "br" in str(content):
        continue
    lyrics += str(content)
    print('in loop'),
    print(lyrics)

print('out of loop'),
print(lyrics)
```

Does the above snippet work for you as expected?

Comment: yes, it does work for the usual list of strings. But, in this case, the songResult variable is a tag that contains the following text and "br" tags: `eien&nbsp;sagasu&nbsp;kimi&nbsp;wa&nbsp;utsurigi&nbsp;na&nbsp;yumemibito
<br>uwaki&nbsp;na&nbsp;yume&nbsp;ni&nbsp;sugari&nbsp;anata&nbsp;wa&nbsp;doko&nbsp;e&nbsp;yuku<br><br>`  . edit: the thing is that, the printing goes alright, but when it comes to saving the line by adding it to the lyrics string, it returns only the last line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this code isn't in another loop such that "lyrics" is not being reset to "". That would cause the symptoms you described (printing in the if statement coming out fine but 'lyrics' only containing the last variable).

Comment: I checked that. I also added another string variable and this time, I concatenated a random string to it with each iteration in the loop. the result was fine. the string variable had the random string repeated as many times as the loop iterated. this means that the problem is originating from the content variable itself. though, I still can't tell what is it exactly.